# Insert js created svg object into existing svg

Tags: javascript, svg

Is there a way to insert svg object like

```
<svg id="fillgauge2" width="19%" height="200"></svg>
<script language="JavaScript">
var config1 = liquidFillGaugeDefaultSettings();
config1.circleColor = "#FF7777";
config1.textColor = "#FF4444";
config1.waveTextColor = "#FFAAAA";
config1.waveColor = "#FFDDDD";
config1.circleThickness = 0.2;
config1.textVertPosition = 0.2;
config1.waveAnimateTime = 1000;
loadLiquidFillGauge("fillgauge2", 67, config1);
</script>
```

into another svg element like

```
<svg
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
width="100%"
height="100%"
id="svg4684"
version="1.1"
viewBox="0 0 1600 1200"><rect
 ry="191.66667"
 rx="23.348978"
 y="136.66667"
 x="326.66666"
 height="383.33334"
 width="246.66667"
 id="wymiennikCwu"
 fill="url(#wymiennikCwuGradient)"
 style="opacity:1;stroke:#868787;stroke-width:5;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
 onclick="getDetails(wymiennikCwu)">
 <object id="fillgauge2" width="19%" height="200"></object>
 </rect></svg>
```

I would like to have "fillgauge2" inside the "rect".
any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

---------------EDIT---------------
I came up with this

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/liquidFillGauge.js"></script>
<style>
    .liquidFillGaugeText { font-family: Helvetica; font-weight: bold; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<svg
 xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
version="1.1"
id="svg2"
viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047"
>
<defs
 id="defs4" />
<metadata
 id="metadata7">
<rdf:RDF>
  <cc:Work
     rdf:about="">
    <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
    <dc:type
       rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
    <dc:title></dc:title>
  </cc:Work>
</rdf:RDF>
</metadata>
<g id="layer1" transform="translate(110,110) rotate(10)">
<rect
   ry="311.772"
   rx="37.883099"
   y="146.64792"
   x="182.85715"
   height="360"
   width="320"
   id="kwadrat"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#f9f9f9;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#3c2a2a;stroke-width:20;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" />
   </g>
   </svg>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function code() {
var bodySelection = d3.select("body");

 var svgSelection = bodySelection.insert("svg")
                            .attr("width", "100")
                           .attr("height", "100")
                           .attr("overflow","visible")
                           .attr("id", "fillgauge2");
    var config1 = liquidFillGaugeDefaultSettings();
    config1.circleColor = "#FF7777";
    config1.textColor = "#FF4444";
    config1.waveTextColor = "#FFAAAA";
    config1.waveColor = "#FFDDDD";
    config1.circleThickness = 0.2;
    config1.textVertPosition = 0.2;
    config1.waveAnimateTime = 1000;
    loadLiquidFillGauge("fillgauge2", 67, config1);
}
window.onload = code;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine when inserting into the body but when i try to insert it to the group where rect is i get this error

> Error: Invalid value for  attribute transform="translate(NaN,NaN)"u @ d3.v3.min.js:1
>   d3.v3.min.js:1 Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="M0,NaNANaN,NaN 0 1,1 0,NaNANaN,NaN 0 1,1 0,NaNZ"o @ d3.v3.min.js:1
>   d3.v3.min.js:1 Error: Invalid value for  attribute transform="translate(NaN,NaN)"u @ d3.v3.min.js:1
>   d3.v3.min.js:1 Error: Invalid value for  attribute transform="translate(NaN,NaN)"u @ d3.v3.min.js:1
>   d3.v3.min.js:1 Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZ"o @ d3.v3.min.js:1
>   d3.v3.min.js:1 Error: Invalid value for  attribute cx="NaN"u @ d3.v3.min.js:1
>   d3.v3.min.js:1 Error: Invalid value for  attribute cy="NaN"u @ d3.v3.min.js:1
>   d3.v3.min.js:1 Error: Invalid value for  attribute r="NaN"u @ d3.v3.min.js:1
>   d3.v3.min.js:1 Error: Invalid value for  attribute transform="translate(NaN,NaN)"u @ d3.v3.min.js:1
>   d3.v3.min.js:1 Error: Invalid value for  attribute transform="translate(NaN,NaN)"u @ d3.v3.min.js:1
>   d3.v3.min.js:4 Error: Invalid value for  attribute transform="translate(NaN,0)"ta.transform @ d3.v3.min.js:4
>   http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   2d3.v3.min.js:1 Error: Invalid value for  attribute transform="translate(NaN,0)"u @ d3.v3.min.js:1
>   12d3.v3.min.js:1 Error: Invalid value for  attribute transform="translate(NaN,0)"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: In SVG the [`rect` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#RectElement) **must not** contain any elements other than animation elements or descriptive elements. This means that neither your above quoted code nor your desired outcome will be a valid SVG document. To have elements visually contain other elements in svg terms you need to render them on top of each other. It is custom to group them using a `g` element to act on a set of linked elements.

Comment: And, yes, there are JavaScript solutions to that. Please adjust your question to specify the output you really want and it should be fairly easy to find a solution that fils your needs.

Comment: exactly as you said i want to have the "fillgauge2" on top of the "rect" element(covering the insides) but still keep the fill gradiant as the background. "rect" should visually contain  "fillgauge2".

Comment: Then fillgauge2 needs to be a subsequent sibling of rect

Comment: Something like this?     `var fillgauge = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","svg");
 fillgauge.setAttribute("id", "fillgauge2");
 fillgauge.setAttribute("width", "19%");
 fillgauge.setAttribute("height", "20%");
    var config1 = liquidFillGaugeDefaultSettings();
    config1.circleColor = "#FF7777";
    config1.textColor = "#FF4444";
    config1.circleThickness = 0.2;
    config1.textVertPosition = 0.2;
    config1.waveAnimateTime = 1000;
    loadLiquidFillGauge("fillgauge2", 67, config1);
    document.getElementById("wymiennikCwu").appendChild(fillgauge);
`

Comment: Who knows, I can't possibly read code in a comment. Put it in the question and format it properly.

Comment: Edited question alredy.Thank you for all your help Robert.

Answer (score 0):

This work but isnt there better solution?

```
 <g>
 <rect
 ry="191.66667"
 rx="23.348978"
 y="136.66667"
 x="326.66666"
 height="383.33334"
 width="246.66667"
 id="wymiennikCwu"
 fill="url(#wymiennikCwuGradient)"
 style="opacity:1;stroke:#868787;stroke-width:5;stroke-miterlimit:4;  stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
 onclick="getDetails(wymiennikCwu)"/>
 <foreignobject x="375.66666" y="255.66667" width="180" height="180">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/liquidFillGauge.js"> </script>
<style>
.liquidFillGaugeText {
font-family: Helvetica;
font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<svg id="pwcwu" width="150" height="200"></svg>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var config1 = liquidFillGaugeDefaultSettings();
    config1.circleColor = "#ff0000";
    config1.textColor = "#FF4444";
    config1.waveTextColor = "#FFAAAA";
    config1.waveColor = "#FFDDDD";
    config1.circleThickness = 0.2;
    config1.textVertPosition = 0.2;
    config1.waveAnimateTime = 1000;
    loadLiquidFillGauge("pwcwu", #{hmiView.pwcwu}, config1);
    </script>
    </foreignobject>
    </g>
```